# What does this line mean in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to understand what this line of code means in Matlab. I know what the plot function does but I can't seem to understand this: `(d - sqrt(T)) * [1,1], [-1,1]`

```
plot((d - sqrt(T)) * [1,1], [-1,1], 'g', 'linewidth', 2)
```

Comment: I'm actually trying to re-write the line of code in Python

Comment: Are you asking what a subtraction , a square root and a multiplication do?

Comment: Hi Sardar, thanks for replying. I know this question seems vague but what I do not understand is [1,1], [-1,1]. For example, we can have plot(x, y, 'g', 'linewidth', 2). So what exactly is "(d - sqrt(T)) * [1,1], [-1,1]"? is it both x and y coordinates?

Comment: `d - sqrt(T)) * [1,1]` is x. ‍‍And ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍`[-1,1]` is y

Comment: thanks, Sardar, I get the whole idea now

Answer (score 1):

The `x` value is `(d - sqrt(T)) * [1,1]` which actually produces `x = [d-sqrt(T), d-sqrt(T)]` assuming that `d` and `T` are both constants; and `y = [-1, 1]`.

This code will therefore plot a vertical green line of thickness 2, between y-values -1 and 1, at the x value of `d-sqrt(T)`.